# Requiring import statements in multiple files which calls one another in python

Tags: python, import

If we have file which contains import statements and functions which uses imported file, can such file be called in another python file. For example

## File1.py

```
import numpy as np

def myfunction:
    val1 = np.arange(4)
    return val1
```

If myfunction has to be used in another script I am using following code

## File2.py

```
 import File1
 newVal = File1.myfunction
```

Is there a way to remove import statement in File1.py? As there can be multiple files like File1.py which would be using numpy module and then import statement has to be written in each file.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Note that any file that imports File1 but does not access numpy *directly* does not need to import numpy.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for reply. But what if we pass np as argument for myfunction?

Comment: Then imports are irrelevant.